# rom overflow and missing references in build for contiki example sky-shell

Tags: shell, gcc, overflow, msp430, contiki

I have been trying to get the example sky-shell to build and am failing at it.
I have tried in contiki-2.6 and contiki-2.7.  I had thought that it's possibly the compiler itself being inefficient or something so when trying in contiki-2.7 I made sure to try msp430-4.5.3, 4.6.3 and 4.7.0 (using the answer to this forum question to switch mspgcc versions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/187253/how-to-update-a-package-from-command-line-gcc-compiler).
None of this seemed to help.  I also tried compiling with "SMALL=0" but this seemed to only increase the overflow.

I then tried commenting out any code in sky-upload.c (such as shell_netfile_init(), shell_rim_init() and shell_rim_netcmd_init()).  This seemed to reduce the compilation enough so that it would get past the overflow in compilation, but now it says that it has missing references in function vuprintf to __udivmodsi4.  I tried researching this issue and it seems that I may somehow be using a different version of gcc for part of the compilation than what I currently think (forum post here: http://sourceforge.net/p/mspgcc/mailman/mspgcc-users/thread/D45E6EE7-2771-41EC-9999-F773C6B22AA4@imag.fr/)

I feel like the example should work with none of the above mentioned init() calls commented out.  It also seems that to ultimately get the example to work as intended (i.e. send ELF files over the air to a mote and then load them) I can't have the above mentioned init() calls commented out and may need even more code on top of what is provided in the example.

I realize that there are two main questions here and typically a post only deals with one at a time, but since they are muddled together I thought it best to post both issues (the overflow and the missing references).

Does anyone know what may be going wrong here?  I am a novice when it comes to all things contiki so please add extra explanation wherever possible :).

Thanks